# Как выбрать строку с помощью чекбокса и вывести сообщение?

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет! Возникло препятствие: https://ibb.co/cc190q Как с помощью JS либо php реализовать следующее: нажатие на чекбокс, кнопку Block, выводится алертом: (qwe was blocked). Либо другое имя в зависимости от выбора.
Заранее спасибо за идеи и помощь.

Comment: дополните свой вопрос кодом. Тут телепатов по скринам маловато

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте одинаковые вопросы. Углубитесь в ответы, внимательно читайте комментарии, пишите уточняющие комментарии, улучшайте вопрос. Но не надо один и тот же вопрос задавать 4 раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вкратце

```
var button = document.getElementById("button-block");
button.onclick = function () {
    var checked_input = document.querySelector("input:checked");
    if (checked_input) {
        alert(checked_input.value + " was blocked")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял суть вопроса

```js
$('#block').on("click", function(){
  $('input:checked').each(function() {//Перебираем все выбранные input
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();//Достаем прородителя(tr) выбранного input
    var name = parent.find('td:eq(1)').text();//У прородителя(tr) ищем 2 по щету td. счет начинается с 0(0 это инпут, 1 это Name, 2 это Last Login
    var date = parent.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var status = parent.find('td:eq(3)').text();
    alert('Name: '+name+'; Date: '+date+'; Status '+status);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="block">Block</button>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last Login</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>qwe</td>
    <td>2018</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>2018</td><td>0</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>  
</table>
```